# Can an Ackerman become a Titan Shifter?

Tags: attack-on-titan

After reading the Manga until the current issue, it kind of feels like to me that it's building to Mikasa is going to become the Female Titan, or that Mikasa is going to inherit the Attack Titan from Eren due to the curse of Ymir.

This raised yet another question about the AoT series, can an Ackerman become a Titan shifter, seeing that this clan is one of the "special clans" that cannot be affected by Titan powers in any way, form or shape?

I would think that they can, given that the Ackerman clan was a "result of Titan Science" before or after the walls were built, explaining their enhanced abilities and skills, but still leaves the burning question, can an Ackerman become a Titan should it be inherited from elsewhere?

***UPDATE***

As of Chapter 112. It is revealed by Eren that the Ackerman Clan can control Titan abilties when in close proximity with a Titan Shifter, or if that Ackerman member has a relatively close bond to said Titan Shifter (e.g. Mikasa and Eren). I feel that this information is relevant to this question, and thus has been added.

Comment: Only people of a specific ethnic group can become Titans. I suspect that the Ackermans aren't supposed to be of that ethnic group (hence the immunity to memory erasing, for example). But at the same time, the Ackermans must have had children with those in the main ethnic group, such that over generations, wouldn't the Ackermans mostly be of the main ethnic group now? So, I don't know what the answer is. I doubt Mikasa can become a Titan though, as she is also half Japanese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably not.

As you've mentioned by yourself, it was said that most Ackermans are immune to effects of titan powers, such as memory manipulation.

It is still not clear, what exactly was done with Ackermans, but apparently their bloodline is so modified, that they can't be considered as Eldians anymore. In one of the recent chapters (I'm not sure, 108 or 109), it was mentioned, that Survey Corps are not even sure if Mikasa can become titan at all, but it wasn't explicitly menioned, is that due to her being Ackerman or due to asian blood mix.

Answer (score 1):

No, an Ackerman cannot become a Titan. In the wiki, it was mentioned that

> they are ['one of the few clans that are not Subjects of Ymir'](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Ackerman_family). Yes, they are immune to the effects of titan powers and most importantly, the [titan injection](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Titan_injection) which transforms someone into a mindless titan and which gives them a chance to inherit a titan-shifter power, only works for Subjects of Ymir.

Contrary to the previous answer,

> the Ackerman family is still considered an Eldian family, as mentioned [here](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Ackerman_family). They were only persecuted since they opposed the First King. Also, to give the reason that 'their bloodline is so modified' is quite incorrect since in the first place, it is not known how little or how much they were modified due to 'Titan Science,' which was first mentioned by Zeke in **Chapter 93**. What is known is that the modification due to 'Titan Science' gave some members of the family an 'awakened power.' As far as I know, the specifics of how the Ackermans were modified is not yet discussed in the manga.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "pure" Ackermans can become titans due to being genetically modified, but since Levi is most likely half Eldian he may have the potential to turn into a tiran given Reiner can turn into a titan despite being half Marleyan. Mikasa might be a little iffy because her mother was a "pure" Asian and we know her father was a member of the Ackerman clan but it was unclear as to whether or not he was half Eldian as well. So it is possible that Levi and Mikasa can turn into titans but there may end up being unintended side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can say for sure that the Ackermans can't transform into titans or become a titan shifter.

**[Spoiler Alert]**
In the later chapters of the manga, after Eren came into contact with Zeke, he was able to talk to all Subjects of Ymir about the rumbling that he was able to start. Among those that were affected were Mikasa and Levi, not to mention, they were also "transported" to the place where "all paths are connected" which only Subjects of Ymir can access. This hints to a certain degree that they're partially Subjects of Ymir.

As for why they're immune to the Founding Titan's power might be precisely due to the Titan Science experiments that were done on them. My theory is that, because their clan/family was tasked to defend the king, a fail-safe was design for them to be immune in a case where the Founding Titan's power falls into the wrong hands.